# Enabled UFW and now i can't connect to SSH

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, startupscript, ufw

I have an Ubuntu server on google compute engine that i have allowed ufw on but forgot to allow port 22 for `ssh` connections and now I cannot access it

- Any idea how can I reverse that?

I also tried to connect using google serial console but i can't remember my instance username and password.

- Where are these set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to run a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) and set username/password in order to access through serial console or directly to modify the ufw writing down in the script the commands you would have used.

> Note that the startup script is run as root.

Answer (score 5):

[This answer from Server Fault solved the problem for me](https://serverfault.com/a/946347/508925) . Use any of the 2 methods. I used the first:

1. **Method 1:** Add startup script on the GCP VM's instance settings page to disable ufw

   ```
   #! /bin/bash
   /usr/sbin/ufw disable
   ```
2. **Method 2**: Attach the boot disk to another instance and modify the file  `/etc/ufw/ufw.conf`

See link for detailed instructions